# SQL : how to retrieve the mean of the previous year?

Tags: sql

I have an issue with my dataset

| Month | Year | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021 | 100 |
| 2 | 2021 | 150 |
| 3 | 2021 | 200 |
| 1 | 2022 | 100 |
| 2 | 2022 | 140 |
| 3 | 2022 | 120 |
| 1 | 2023 | 100 |
| 2 | 2023 | 100 |
| 3 | 2023 | 100 |

I want to add a new column with, for each row, the sales average of the previous year to obtain this :

| Month | Year | Sales | Avg Sales Previous year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021 | 100 | null |
| 2 | 2021 | 150 | null |
| 3 | 2021 | 200 | null |
| 1 | 2022 | 100 | 150 |
| 2 | 2022 | 140 | 150 |
| 3 | 2022 | 120 | 150 |
| 1 | 2023 | 100 | 120 |
| 2 | 2023 | 100 | 120 |
| 3 | 2023 | 100 | 120 |

I tried this :

lag("Sales",1)OVER (
PARTITION BY "month"
ORDER BY "year", "month" ASC
)

But it don't work for each rows

Do yo have a solution ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same approach as *am2* just for an update statement as you ask how to populate a column with the average value.

```sql
UPDATE data
SET year_mean = subquery.mean
FROM (
  SELECT year, avg(sales) as "mean" FROM data
  GROUP BY year
) as subquery
WHERE data.year = (subquery.year - 1);
```

The exact syntax may vary depending on your DBMS but it should be possible to adapt this to every DBMS.

Example with postgres:
[DB<>Fiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/zlgC52rY)

Answer (score 0):

I Do not know, whether there is a tricky way with windows functions to bind it on the average of the previos year. But you can easily do this that way (inline views):

```
WITH AvgYear AS (
    SELECT YEAR, AVG(SALES) AVG_SALES  
    FROM XY
    GROUP BY YEAR)
SELECT 
    XY.MONTH, XY.YEAR, XY.SALES, 
    AvgYear.AVG_SALES AVG_SALES_LAST_YEAR,
    AVG(XY.SALES) OVER (PARTITION BY XY.YEAR) AVG_SALES_THIS_YEAR   
FROM XY LEFT JOIN AvgYear ON (XY.YEAR-1) = AvgYear.YEAR
ORDER BY XY.YEAR, XY.MONTH
```

The average Sale for this year is no problem with windows- functions, as you can see.

Comment: It seemed to me you used oracle or something like this. My Query is designed for Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution that can solve your question.

```
SELECT 
    s.month, 
    s.year, 
    s.sales, 
    sales_year.avg_sales as avg_sales_prev_year
FROM salesdata s
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT 
        year, 
        round(avg(sales),0) as avg_sales
    from salesdata
GROUP BY year) as sales_year 
on sales_year.year = s.year - 1
```